# Best way to decode transaction input on the client side

Tags: web3js, transactions, javascript, decoding

I need to decode transaction input on the client side. Libraries like [ethereum-input-data-decoder](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-input-data-decoder) needs NodeJS dependencies like `fs`.

Now I decode the one type of contract methods as follows:

```
const getERC20TransferByHash = async (hash) => {
  const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(hash)
  if (
    tx !== null &&
    (tx.input.length === 138 || tx.input.slice(2, 10) === 'a9059cbb')
  ) {
    const receiver = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress('0x' + tx.input.slice(34, 74))
    const amount = web3.utils.toBN('0x' + tx.input.slice(74))
    const contractAddress = tx.to
    const sender = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(tx.from)
    return { receiver, amount, contractAddress, hash, sender }
  }
  return {}
}
```

Decoding by `web3.utils.toAscii(transaction.input)` also don't work.

Is there a single way to make it easy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try [`decodeParameters`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-abi.html?highlight=decode#decodeparameters)? Like:

```js
const erc20TransferABI = [{
        type: "address",
        name: "receiver"
    },{
        type: "uint256",
        name: "amount"
    }];
const decoded = web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(
    erc20TransferABI,
    tx.input.slice(10)); // Or (11), not sure
```

Even perhaps, take `erc20TransferABI` from the ABI file itself.

Comment: The first 10 bytes is the signature function?

Comment: The first 4 bytes, which appear as 8 characters when represented as a string. Then if you also need to remove `"0x"` from the string, then that makes 10 characters to remove in all.

Comment: Update the answer.Instead of objects with keys `name` and `type`, you need paste array with types as string (`address`, `uint256`).

Comment: What version of Web3 are you using? Perhaps this array or detailed object way for the ABI could be due to versions.